# How do I deep clone JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const obj1 = { food: 'pizza', car: 'ford' };
let obj2 = obj1;
```

In the above example, I want to do deep copy of obj1 in obj2 .

Comment: Is it JSON or is it a javascript object?

Comment: not sure why you want to deep-clone the object in your example? A shallow copy should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `_.cloneDeep` 
https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// => false
```